# Update column from integer[] to jsonb[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

First off, for this I'm using Elixir (Ecto) but I think I'll be better off running a raw SQL statement on the migration.

I have a column which is an array of integers; due to requirement changes I need to convert this array of integers to an array of objects, `jsonb[]` in this case. This isn't looking quite right for me since converting from `integer[]` to `jsonb[]` is not possible (At least not automatically)

I've been trying to cast both types but its just not resulting; I've even tried to convert to string then to jsonb but that doesn't seem to work.

Now I'm looking for the best way to do this, not the simplest, just the best or correct way to do this. I was thinking about creating a temp column, copying the values from the old column there and renaming maybe? What would be the correct SQL statement for this?

By the way, I'm getting hit by this hint too `hint: You might need to specify "USING table_name::jsonb[]"` but using `USING column_name::jsonb[]` does not do the trick, neither `CAST (column_name as jsonb)`.

If it was as simple as I thought it would work with `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE jsonb[] USING column_name::jsonb[]`. Let me know if I've not provided enough information, thanks.

Comment: What do you want the contents of the objects to be?  It is a bit odd of have an array of JSONB, since JSON supports arrays inside itself.  Are you sure you want JSONB[], and not a single JSONB which contains an JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `array_to_json()` and then cast to jsonb or just `to_jsonb()`:

```
select x.*, array_to_json(ari)::jsonb,
       to_jsonb(ari)
from (select array[1, 2, 3] as ari) x;
```

If you want to change the type in place, use `alter table`:

```
alter table t alter column ari type jsonb using to_jsonb(ari);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d9a67cdbcae84234ee27c9a634629416) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, how would I incorporate this into an `alter` statement? Asking since I've noticed you're casting to `jsonb` here instead, does the use of `array` helps on converting to `jsonb[]` here or...?

Answer (score 0):

The below construct will work to get you a JSONB[] from INT[].  But technically what you get is not an array of JSON **objects** (which refers specifically to the hash-table like thingies), it just an array of JSON thingies which each contain a scalar with the JSON type of "number".  If that isn't what you want, you will have to describe what you want.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE jsonb[] USING column_name::text::jsonb[]
```